# How to prevent Firefox Android Accessibility feature scaling up text size

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-android

The Accessibility setting in Firefox Android scales up the text on a webpage. As you can see, it is experience breaking and ruins the UI of the website.

I've tried to stop this from happening using CSS and using Meta properties. Below is what I have tried, but it doesn't work. Anybody know how to stop this scaling from happening?

```
<style>

body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  text-size-adjust: none;
  transform: scale(1);
  zoom: 1;
}

</style>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do hope this isn't possible. Maybe you need to rethink your website UI to allow for different font scaling.

Comment: Look at the search bar on Google, completely ruined

Comment: Could you show us an example of your code which is being 'ruined'. It is troubling that it cannot cope with font scaling - do you have some built-in absolute unit values being used? As @Alohci has commented, I do hope it isn't possible to override an accessibility aid.

Comment: This is a technical question, not a moral one